# ATK4 - Page_EntityManager

Tags: php, user-interface, atk4

With Agile Toolkit, how should I link a column value in a row to a webpage using Page_EntityManager?

Answer (score 1):

EntityManager is now depreciated and you should use CRUD instead. It supports "link" column.

http://book.agiletoolkit.org/views/crud.html